# Enable Chrome extension action button only on one host

Tags: google-chrome-extension, permissions, manifest

I've been trying to migrate one of my Chrome extensions to manifest v3, and I'm having trouble with the `page_action`. In manifest v3, the `page_action` and `browser_action` are merged into `action`, which is all good, but it's not clear to me how I can get the behavior I had previously with the new APIs.

A bit of background; the extension in question is only supposed to run on one host (let's say https://example.com). As such, I want to grey out the icon on pages with a different host. It has a popup with some settings but the main functionality is inserted via a content script (this works).

The old extension using manifest v2 used

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "...",
    "description": "...",
    "version": "...",
    "permissions": ["declarativeContent", "storage", "https://example.com/", "tabs"],
    "page_action": {
        "default_icon": { ... },
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "icons": { ... },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["content.js"],
        "matches": ["https://example.com/*", "https://www.example.com/*"]
    }]
}
```

and in `background.js` I used

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(){
    const pageUrl = {hostEquals: 'www.example.com'};
    const {
        onPageChanged,
        PageStateMatcher,
        ShowPageAction
    } = chrome.declarativeContent;

    onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function(){
        onPageChanged.addRules([{
            conditions: [new PageStateMatcher({pageUrl})],
            actions: [new ShowPageAction()]
        }]);
    });
});
```

this works fine and the icon gets greyed out except on https://example.com. When migrating, the manifest looks like

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": ...,
    "description": ...,
    "version": ...,
    "permissions": ["storage", "tabs", "declarativeContent", "activeTab"],
    "background": {"service_worker": "service-worker.js"},
    "action": {
        "default_icon": { ... },
        "default_popup": "popup/index.html"
    },
    "icons": { ... },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["*://*.example.com/*"],
        "js": ["content/detect-theme.js"]
    }]
}
```

I cannot seem to get this to work properly. I've tried adding `host_permissions`, removing the `declarativeContent`-related code (as it doesn't seem to affect the icon whatsoever) but the extension stays available on all hosts. I know I can use the `chrome.action.enable` and `chrome.action.disable` methods to simulate this behavior but it seems overkill for such a simple use-case.

Actually, the action being available even on other pages is not breaking by any means, but I would like to make it more clear to my users that the extension only does things on https://example.com and nowhere else. Perhaps this is not even the right approach; if it isn't, I accept that as an answer as well.

TLDR; how do I only enable the (page-)action on a specific host with manifest v3?

Comment: ManifestV3 is still in development and full of bugs. You can report this problem on https://crbug.com if it wasn't reported already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue myself, and I just solved it!

I fixed it by disabling the extension in the handler before adding the activation rule. I've removed the actual handler for brevity.

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {

    chrome.action.disable(); // The important line!

    // actual handler...
});
```

I would guess that `ShowPageAction` doesn't disable the extension by default anymore.

Comment: That does seem to work. It feels a bit risky because it seems like this would disable it in general on all tabs, but the behaviour of `chrome.action.disable` when no parameter is given is (as of writing this) [not very well-documented](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/#method-disable). I suppose it'll have to do for now, until either the behaviour is (more) defined or until this method breaks ;)